# How to create a menu from content type fields found on a node?

Tags: 7, routes, nodes

I have a content type with 4 text areas I would like to make into 4 separate "pages" by creating a menu dynamically based on fields.

Is this possible? Reason I'd like to do this is to create a single content type a person creates with the necessary fields and then has a menu created dynamically from these fields if they contain data.

The only other option I can think of is creating multiple content types and then combining them.

Comment: Combining content types seems like a bad idea. You should have a look at the Views module. There you can select what fields to display and you can transform them into links giving you some sort of menu. However you can't create a page form only a field value. So where will they link to?

Comment: Also can't you use basic taxonomy (tags) for this? Just create a content type and a field that can contain up to 4 tags.

Comment: I am trying to give them a menu from the fields. I think views might be it... just wrapping my head around how to...

Answer (score 1):

You could build this with the Field Group (https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module, which will allow you to group your content fields into horizontal tabs, vertical tabs, accordions and more. By default, groups with only empty fields will be hidden, i.e., they will not display in the "menu".

While this would not create separate pages, your use of the word in quotes makes me think this would be an acceptable answer.

There is a decent tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GU_tb4K-f4.